# Enable InAppBrowser in PhoneGap Windows Phone app for build in Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone

I'm developing a PhoneGap app inside a WP7 project and strugging with the InAppBrowser: I saw that there's a file `InAppBrowser.cs` already included in my Project (Phonegap 2.9.1), and I even downloaded the `InAppBrowser.js` file from its git repo and included that in my page. But calling `window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/, '_system');` still doesn't launch the system browser app.

My `config.xml` looks as follows:

```
<widget>
<access origin="*"/>
<features>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Device" onload="false"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Compass" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Accelerometer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Camera"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="wp-package" value="NetworkStatus"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Contacts"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="wp-package" value="File"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="wp-package" value="FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Geolocation"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Media"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Battery"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="wp-package" value="InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Notification"/>
    </feature>
</features>
```

What else is needed to make the InAppBrowser finally work?

Side note: Building the app in *PhoneGap Build* makes these links (and the InAppBrowser) work correctly, but has too many restrictions, so I'd like to build it locally.